# X-Rite Colorchecker Passport Photo 2: where can I find the spectral reflectance data for the first two pages?

Tags: colorchecker

Similar to this [Colorchecker Classic discussion](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/119359/where-can-i-find-color-data-for-x-rite-colorchecker-classic), I'd like to ask for the spectral reflectance data (or at least for the colour specifications) of the first two pages of the *X-Rite Colorchecker Passport Photo 2* (i.e. produced **after** the change in dyes, after November 2014).

- X-Rite only seems to provide specifications for the 24-patch page, which is page 2.
- `argyllcms`, `dcamprof` don't have this data in the references directories.

Has anyone here measured (or found the specifications of) the "enhancements" page of this product?
Thanks very much.